# Convert type of entity to subtype with NHibernate/Hibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, orm, inheritance, casting

Would you please help me to find out better solution for the following issue...
There is an hierarchy at my domain model:

```
class Document { 
  Int Id; 
  String Title; 
}
class Agreement : Document { 
  DateTime Signed; 
}
```

Persistent strategy is Table-per-class. I.e. 2 tables: 'Documents' (Id, ...) and 'Agreements' (Fk_document, ...)

First operation is the registration of document. At this moment I don't know document's real type. So I create new Document and fill its property 'Title'.

After some time I receive additional information. According with it the previously registered document actually was an agreement which was signed at some date. Now I can fill property 'Signed' of Agreement.

But to do this it is necessary to somehow convert type from Document to Agreement. I could make SQL-call like this:

```
INSERT INTO AGREEMENTS (FK_DOCUMENT, SIGNED_DATE) VALUES ( 1111111, TO_DATE('01-01-2000') )
```

(Where '1111111' is Id which Hibernate assign to document while saving it first time)

I believe it is not best way at all! But I couldn't find any others...
Thank you!

(I thought up this example, real use-case is rather difficult and I don't want to encumber the question. Documents must be saved as soon as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to 'change the class' of a persisted entity it's a sign that you don't really want to model this as a class hierarchy. Instead, use composition.

Comment: Thanks! In general, I'm agree with you. In one of future versions I will add to model something like a Categories. So Document will include a property like AgreementCategory with agreement's properties in it. It will be a sort of architectural decision. But now the question is - how to 'change the class' by Nhibernate methods (if it is possible at all).

Comment: @barser: you have to resort to SQL or create a new instance copying the old object's property values.